# Laravel Create Collection from Collection

Tags: laravel

I have a Post model that has a Many-To-Many relationship with a Topic model. In my controller, I have retrieved a collection of posts for a particular user. Now, I am trying to create a collection of all the topics related to that collection of posts.

My collection of posts is defined as such...

```
// Get all posts created by this user
$posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get()->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

If I do $post->topic->topic_name I get the name of the topic for that specific post, but I want a collection of the topics. There should be 3. I have tried the following with no luck...

```
foreach ($posts as $post)
{
   $topics = $post->topic;
}
```

The $topics collection just stops as the first topic and does not include the rest. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: a post has multiple topic??in that case do you have a pivot table??

Comment: please share your  relationship

Answer (score 0):

You said it is a many to many relation, then in your Post model you should define your relation like this

```
public function topics()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Topic');
}
```

Then in your query do topics instead topic.

Comment: also, I recommend you to change the order of the sortByDesc like this ->sortByDesc('created_at')->get() so the order can happen at a data base level instead of a PHP level.